American Airlines agents could not rebook in Etihad flight
I had a confirmed economy ticket from Houston to Abu Dhabi with Etihad, and the first part of the trip from Houston to Chicago was operated by American Airlines. My flight from Houston was scheduled to leave at 6:30 AM, and I arrived at the check-in line by 4:45 AM. I was 10th in line, and there was only one person handling the Economy check-in for American Airlines. By the time it was my turn, it was about 5:50 AM, and they told me I couldn't check in for the flight. They tried to rebook me on the same flight for the next day and gave me a printed itinerary.
When I contacted Etihad, they said the American Airlines agent hadn't issued the tickets. I went back to the line and spoke to a different agent. She couldn't fix the issue and said the Etihad system was rejecting the changes she was trying to make. She contacted the American Airlines Helpdesk, but they had the same problem. She suggested I contact Etihad again.
When I contacted Etihad again, they told me to contact American Airlines. Frustrated, I asked Etihad to cancel my reservation, which they did without charging any cancellation fees because the flight from Houston to Chicago that I had missed was delayed by 90 minutes.
I understand that I should have reached the airport at least by 4 AM and I was at fault. However, in situations like this, when both airlines are not helping the passenger, what should be the course of action?

What is your desired resolution?

I have to admit I’m puzzled. A single AA agent in IAH? Over one hour to process 9 passengers? Had you checked in online? Used the kiosks? I suppose you just had to drop bags?

I’m puzzled by the whole scenario. If I’d stood in a queue behind just 9 other people for nearly an hour watching the clock tick round to gate closure deadline, I would have flagged the urgency to the check-in agent long before it got to 5:50

If that really happened as described than A LOT of people would have missed their flight this day.

I first tried to use the Kiosks but it printed a message saying that I need to go see  an agent. Yes there was only one dedicated agent for Economy check-ins although the two agents who were servicing the  Priority lines were helping occasionally when the Priority lines became empty but that was not very frequent.

Since I am not a frequent traveler, I was wondering when both airlines seemed  unhelpful what should one do.

@erase.ego I don’t think either airline is under any obligation to help. As I see it your options are to pursue a complaint or do nothing.


what should be the course of action?

If Etihad cancelled your reservation and refunded your ticket without charging a cancellation fee, you should re-book the trip and make sure to turn up for check-in earlier than on this occasion.
If you believe that AA is responsible for your experience, make a formal complaint

I am not blaming either parties since one could argue that I was at fault for not reaching the airport sufficiently early ( I was there 1 hour 45 minutes before the departure).  My issue is neither of them were able to rebook me. AA being unable to and Etihad for sending me back to AA to rebook the flight. I was lucky that I could cancel without a penalty.
